# How to Post data(Name,Phoneno,Address,etc) with multiple image path('n' number) on Single Click in Android

Tags: android

How to Post data such as Name, Phoneno, Address, etc including multiple image paths on single click in android.How to write the post method for this in android?
I am able to save text data but couldn't able to add multiple image paths to an Object.
My JSON structure is like this:

```
{
  "Name":"",
  "Phoneno":"",
  "Address":"",
  "Status":"",
  "ODC":{
         "Item":"",
         "ItemType":"",
         "Image_url":""
       }
}
```

Images are getting saved in server. How to save the multiple image path to "Image_url"??
A sample code will be much helpful.

Thanks

Comment: It does not make sense to put the path to an image in the data you are going to upload to the server as the server is expecting images i can read from your post. So you have to put your images in the json data. Please explain better what should heppen.

Comment: i have a horizontal view where i am adding multiple images dynamically into it and those images are stored in a folder , i have e 3 textviews where i am giving input such as details(such as details of the items,current date and Order number) and a Button(Save).so my question is when i click save button the data should be added to the server?

Comment: That is very unsufficient info and not to the point when you speak of 'data' should be 'added' to the server. We are not interested in your gui. You have to tell what you want to upload to your server. Reread my first comment and answer to the point please.

Comment: i need to post multiple images('n' numbers) to the server with some data in single http post..how to do this?

Comment: `with some data`. That is not very much to the point.